# How to access SharePoint 2013 Online Site with the anonymous user

Tags: sharepoint-online

I wonder how the default site or the user-created site can be accessed with anonymous user.
In my trial version of `SharePoint Online`. I found I need to provide the user/password to access the `Sites` in there. Is it the necessary to `SharePoint Online`? Thanks.

Below are the `Sites` created.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't allow anonymous access to any sharepoint content. In an Enterprise account you can hack the permissions with this:

http://anonymous365.codeplex.com/

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/195181.aspx

http://365tutor.org/enable-anonymous-access-in-office-365-public-sites